# Check if app belongs to system apps or to apps signed with platform key

Tags: android, android-launcher

I am developing custom Android launcher and I have an option to **uninstall** apps directly from program list. Now, I would like to remove **uninstall** option for apps that can't get uninstalled, i.e. system apps, apps signed with platform keys...

I found in `ActivityInfo` class following flags

```java
    /**
     * Value for {@link #privateFlags}: whether this app is signed with the
     * platform key.
     * @hide
     */
    public static final int PRIVATE_FLAG_SIGNED_WITH_PLATFORM_KEY = 1 << 20;

    /**
     * Value for {@link #privateFlags}: whether this app is pre-installed on the
     * system_ext partition of the system image.
     * @hide
     */
    public static final int PRIVATE_FLAG_SYSTEM_EXT = 1 << 21;
```

but apparently, I get `Unresolved reference: PRIVATE_FLAG_SYSTEM_EXT` compilation error, even though these flags are `public` and `static`. I am not sure why is that.

Is there any other way so I can check for given package name does that app belong to to system apps or to apps signed with platform key?

Checking for `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM` and `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP` flags doesn't work for me for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM` and `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP` flags **do work**, but they were tested against the wrong flags. Here is the correct code:

```kotlin
val applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0)
val isSystem =
                (applicationInfo.flags and ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM != 0) ||
                (applicationInfo.flags and ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP != 0)
```

Comment: consider flagging own answer as accepted (assuming it works ;) )

Comment: After posting an answer, I need to wait for 24 hours to accept the answer as correct, but thanks, for reminding me.